# Use Flatbuffers to read data of previously written binary files

Tags: c++, flatbuffers

I have a binary file that contains the data that I want to load into a Flatbuffer object. Just as a toy example, I'm using the following schema:

```
namespace SingleInt;
table Single{
    value:uint32;
}
root_type Single;
```

Consider that my binary file contains exactly this information: an `unsigned int` value, and nothing else. In this case, I stored the value `5` on my file. I'm trying to assign and display the content of my binary file into my Flatbuffer object by using the following method:

```
void readFbs(){
    int fd = open("myfile", O_RDONLY, 0);
    unsigned int* memmap = (unsigned int*)mmap(0, sizeof(unsigned int), PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    auto myfile = SingleInt::GetSingle(memmap);
    std::cout<<myfile->value()<<std::endl;
}
```

The output is the value `0`, instead of the value `5` that I thought I'd get.

My question is: knowing how a binary file was serialized and written, if I create a schema that represents it, is it possible to load its content into a Flatbuffer object?

Edit: function to write data

```
void writebin(){
    unsigned int var = 5;
    std::ofstream OutFile;
    OutFile.open("myfile", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    OutFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&var), sizeof(var));
    OutFile.close();
}
```

Comment: Can you also supply your serialization code? The code above looks like it should work, assuming the mmap has the right parameters, which I don't know off the top of my head. Also, a FlatBuffer isn't a `unsigned int *`, but that also shouldn't matter for this case.

Comment: @Aardappel I edited my post and added the function to write data. Also, all flags for mmap seems okay. I also tried to read the whole file into a buffer (like the example on the Flatbuffers' page) and had the same output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your writing code just writes a naked `int` to a file. You need to instead use the FlatBuffers functions to write something that is compatible with the FlatBuffers format, e.g.

```
FlatBufferBuilder fbb;
fbb.Finish(CreateSingle(fbb, 5));
// Now write the buffer starting at fbb.GetBufferPointer() for fbb.GetSize() to a file.
```

More details at https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/flatbuffers_guide_tutorial.html

Comment: So in case I want to load a binary file with multiple fields I need to first parse it, create all its fields and then create a flatbuffer object? Isn’t there a way to pass the binary file to the builder and it creates the structure according to the size of the fields?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. If there was a second field, you'd simply add another parameter to `CreateSingle`. No "parsing" required on the receiving end.